# Wordpress cookie error prevents me from logging in

Tags: wordpress, cookies

I have come across a login error due to cookies. I have attempted the diagnosis but the error is still persistent. I cleared cookies and changes the settings and followed the options. I also watched a video on it to see if I might have missed a step.

Here is the problem

Error: cookies are blocked due to unexpected output. For help, please see this documentation or try the support forums.

I am unsure exactly what I must do at this stage. I tried clearing all plugins in case that might have caused some issues. But nothing happened. I am not sure why all of a sudden I get kicked out and it requests that I have cookies on (not that I don't)

I am a student and non-techy at least at the moment

website assignmentplanner.000webhostapp.com
[image]